# ethzasl_ptam installation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi
i am a new in ros domaine , trying to install ethzasl_ptam with fuerte any help pls    os : ubuntu 10.04 lonovo i7core 64bit.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60432/ethzasl_ptam-installation/) by [houssamou](https://answers.ros.org/users/4657/houssamou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i think the pbroblem is with fuerte version or some thing like that
rosdep never works for me

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource ptam
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

---

Originally posted by [houssamou](https://answers.ros.org/users/4657/houssamou/) with karma: 16 on 2013-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0